# Is there a simple way to write an ODT using Python?

Tags: python, uno, odt

My point is that using either **pod** (from appy framework, which is a pain to use for me) or the **OpenOffice UNO** bridge that seems soon to be deprecated, and that requires OOo.org to run while launching my script is *not satisfactory at all*.

Can anyone point me to a neat way to produce a simple yet clean ODT (tables are my priority) without having to code it myself all over again ?

edit: I'm giving a try to **ODFpy** that seems to do what I need, more on that later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your mileage with odfpy may vary. I didn't like it - I ended up using a template ODT, created in OpenOffice, oppening the contents.xml with ziplib and elementtree, and updating that. (In your case, it would create only the relevant table rows and table cell nodes), then recorded everything back.

It is actually straightforward, but for making ElementTree properly work with the XML namespaces. (it is badly documente)  But it can be done. I don't have the example, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm thinking that it will be limited as you said. But what's the most important for now is that my Python program is really user-friendly and for that I don't what user to create their own templates, because non experimented users are not at ease with templates : so the more is on the programs part, the better.

Answer (score 5):

To edit odt files, my answer may not help, but if you want to create new odt files, you can use QTextDocument, QTextCursor and QTextDocumentWriter in [PyQt4](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download). A simple example to show how to write to an odt file:

```
>>>from pyqt4 import QtGui
# Create a document object
>>>doc = QtGui.QTextDocument()
# Create a cursor pointing to the beginning of the document
>>>cursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(doc)
# Insert some text
>>>cursor.insertText('Hello world')
# Create a writer to save the document
>>>writer = QtGui.QTextDocumentWriter()
>>>writer.supportedDocumentFormats()
[PyQt4.QtCore.QByteArray(b'HTML'), PyQt4.QtCore.QByteArray(b'ODF'), PyQt4.QtCore.QByteArray(b'plaintext')]
>>>odf_format = writer.supportedDocumentFormats()[1]
>>>writer.setFormat(odf_format)
>>>writer.setFileName('hello_world.odt')
>>>writer.write(doc) # Return True if successful
True
```

QTextCursor also can insert tables, frames, blocks, images. More information. More information at:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextcursor.html

As a bonus, you also can print to a pdf file by using QPrinter.